# How to use rules to accomplish specific variable factors in synthpop?

Tags: r, dplyr, synthpop

I have run into a series of challenges using the "rules" function for the [synthpop package on R](https://www.synthpop.org.uk/get-started.html) and would greatly appreciate advice or assistance.

In short, I have a dataset of several variables that I would like to produce "synthetic data" from   - and I have been able to do this part successfully. However, I have struggled to successfully use the "rules" function, which allows me to define specific relationships between specific variables in the data that will then "guide" what my final synthetic data looks like.

My understanding of synthpop is that you can use the "rules" functions for this. I have been unable to code any rules to accomplish this. First, I'll outline my dataset and variables and then I'll outline the two rules I want to try and create.

Dataset:

My dataset is a number of variables breaking down entities that have "paid" and "received" variables, as well as a "net" variable.

The net variable in the original data is naturally a sum of the other two.
Thus, I want to construct my dataset so that the net variable produced by synthpop is still always a summary of the added value of the other two variables together. Therefore,

- net = paid - received

The second restriction is that the "received" amounts have to be capped so they cannot go above a set value in my new, synthetic data (for simplicity's sake, let's say "700"). However, some of the original input data does go above 700.

- received <= 700

I cannot remove these due to the project requirements, but the cap must be in for the new "synthetic" data.

My "true" dataset looks something like this (and I want the synthetic data output to be guided by the same "restrictions"):

| YEAR | IDENTIFIER | payed | received | net |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | A1 | 100 | 400 | -300 |
| 2001 | A2 | 150 | 150 | 0 |
| 2002 | A2 | 150 | 150 | 0 |
| 2003 | A2 | 300 | 900 | -600 |
| 2002 | A3 | 900 | 700 | 200 |
| 2002 | A4 | 800 | 700 | 100 |
| 1999 | A5 | 750 | 700 | 50 |
| 2000 | A6 | 650 | 700 | -50 |

Then I would want my synthetic dataset to give an output for a "theoretical" synthetic data output for A1 to be something that would follow these rules:

| YEAR | IDENTIFIER | payed | received | net |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2003 | A3 | 600 | 700 | -100 |
| 2003 | A4 | 700 | 600 | 100 |

Please don't look at the specific numbers to estimate any statistical relationship, I'm just using this as an example of how I want the output to "follow the rules".

As you can see in my examples:

1. The amount for "received" generated in my synthetic data is never above 700.
2. Net is always a function of (payed - received)

Simply trying to limit this variable in the rules.list and rules.value.list of course in an approach like

```
rules.list <- list(received = "received > 700")

rules.value.list <- list(received = "received <= 700")
```

Gives me the error of

> "Error: Variable(s) used in missing data rules for receivable have to
> be synthesized BEFORE the variables they apply to."

Obviously, this is an order problem - I'm restricting the data before I ever make it. However, I cannot for the life of me think of any other alternative to handling this issue without changing the other data.

With respect to the second problem (making it so any synthetic output of net is always payable + receivable), I've tried various combinations including:

```
rules.list <- list(“net =  'payed' + ' received’")

rules.value.list <- list(net = "'payed' + 'received'")
```

which gives me "unexpected variables in rules": (the above), or the rule is successfully parsed, but not applied (no error message, no change)

The rest of my code is

```
library(dplyr)
library(synthpop)
library(dplyr)

synth.test <- (data, method = 'cart', rules = rules.list, rvalues = rules.value.list, minnumlevels = 5, seed =5)
```

Please note as I stated, this code works fine other than the rules lists not giving the outcomes I want.